# How to display only one UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark at a time

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having a problem with the following code that should allow only one table row to be selected and display a checkmark. Currently there are multiple checkmarks being displayed in the rows.

thanks for any help

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Save the row selected to nsuserdefaults
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setObject:cell.textLabel.text forKey:@"countrySaved"];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-tick.png"];

        UIButton *checkmarkBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        [checkmarkBtn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [checkmarkBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 19, 19)];
        [checkmarkBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = checkmarkBtn;

    } else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

       UIButton *checkmarkBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
       [checkmarkBtn setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [checkmarkBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
       [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = checkmarkBtn;

    }

}
```

I saw on some posts that I have to include the following, but I am unsure about how to implement that within the code.

```
 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewAccessoryNone;

  if (indexPath.row == index) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
  }
```

Comment: just reload tableview first when u click row
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Save the row selected to nsuserdefaults
     [aTableView reloadData];
     then your code...
}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677218/only-one-uitableviewcellaccessorycheckmark-allowed-at-a-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check with this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Save the row selected to nsuserdefaults

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setObject:cell.textLabel.text forKey:@"countrySaved"];
    [prefs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row] forKey:@"selectedRow"];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int val = [[prefs objectForKey:@"selectedRow"] intValue];
if (indexPath.row == val)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-tick.png"];

    UIButton *checkmarkBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [checkmarkBtn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkmarkBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 19, 19)];
    [checkmarkBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = checkmarkBtn;

} else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

   UIButton *checkmarkBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [checkmarkBtn setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [checkmarkBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
   [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = checkmarkBtn;

}
```

Comment: Please check and tell me if there is any other issues !

Comment: thanks for your post :) I'm getting a "bad receiver type" error on this line: int val = [[prefs setObject:cell.textLabel.text forKey:@"selectedRow"] intValue];

Comment: that worked great! the only thing is that when you select another row the checkmark remains on the row that was originally selected and doesn't change to the new row

Comment: Why store the selected row in user defaults? And why call cellForRowAtIndexPath from the data source out to the table view to get a reference to a cell you already have in the method?

Comment: @CarlVeazey I have to store the value of the selection. this is a user prefs table. the selections/settings the user makes here changes another table view elsewhere in the app

Comment: @hanumanDev: are you using the same code ? please check the val in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Checkwhether it is previous value or not !